# how to convert 24 bit bmp file to 16 color bmp file in java

Tags: java, image

I am currently in a situation where I have to convert the image files to Java.

During data communication, the bmp file was created and transmitted using the existing usage method, but due to a new problem, the bmp file format needs to be added and transmitted.

In the traditional method, the bmp file was created using Buffered Image and ImageIO
In this way, we have confirmed that a 24 bit bmp file is being created.

During bmp file generation, the file must be created using 16 colors

We have confirmed that you can change the format to the desired format using IndexColorModel.

There was a problem using IndexColorModel.

```
public static BufferedImage changeFormat( BufferedImage img )   {
    BufferedImage convertImage = null;
    
    try {
            
            byte[] reds = {
                    (byte)0x00, (byte)0xff, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00 };
            byte[] greens = {
                    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0xff, (byte)0x00 };
            byte[] blues = {
                    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0xff };

            IndexColorModel icm = new IndexColorModel(4, 4, reds, greens, blues);

            convertImage = new BufferedImage ( 
                                            img.getWidth()
                                            , img.getHeight()
                                            , BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED
                                            , icm
                );
            

        Graphics2D graphics2D = convertImage.createGraphics();
        graphics2D.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        graphics2D.dispose();
        
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return convertImage;
}
```

We used the above source code to designate the IndexColorModel,
A new image is created according to the image size, the right half has disappeared, the left image is stretched, and the extended part has a black background.

The image size is 32×16 (width×length).

How do I get a complete image file?

input Image : [image: input Image] (24 Bit BMP Image)

output Image: [image: output Image]( 16Color BMP Image)

Image results to be output : [image: Image results to be output] (16 Color  BMP Image)

Comment: Please add a minimal, runnable example which illustrates your problem

Comment: @tgdavies    i was add picture, and remove some arguments of the method.
thanks for your comment.

Comment: It's also no clear whether you want a 16 bit image or a 16 colour (4-bit) image.

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks. i edit for to be output description to result.. i want get 16 color image. I'm trying, but it's not easy.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved with the 'Image4J' library.

example:

```
import net.sf.image4j.util.ConvertUtil;

BufferedImage resultImg = ConvertUtil.convert4( (BufferedImage) sourceImg );
```